# Error in geom_arc_bar() : could not find function "geom_arc_bar"

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I'm new to R and I'm trying to create a pie chart using geom_arc_bar() but I'm encountering this intermittent error.

`Error in geom_arc_bar() : could not find function "geom_arc_bar"`

I summarized the dataset into a table that has all the info to help me set up the pie chart:

```
> pie_data
# A tibble: 5 × 7
  city        sales end_angle start_angle mid_angle hjust vjust
  <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 San Antonio  1485     0.500       0         0.250     0     0
2 Austin       1656     1.06        0.500     0.778     0     0
3 Dallas       3066     2.09        1.06      1.57      0     1
4 Houston      4494     3.60        2.09      2.84      0     1
5 Other        7971     6.28        3.60      4.94      1     0
```

And this is my code causing that error:

```
pie_data %>% 
    ggplot() +
    aes(
        x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0.4, r = 1,
        start = start_angle, end = end_angle,
        fill = city
    ) +
    geom_arc_bar() +
    geom_text(
        aes(
            x = 1.05 * sin(mid_angle),
            y = 1.05 * cos(mid_angle),
            label = city,
            hjust = hjust, vjust = vjust
        )
    ) +
    coord_fixed(
        xlim = c(-1.5, 1.65),
        ylim = c(-1.25, 1.25)
    ) +
    labs(
        title = "Houses Sold in Texas in 2015"
    ) +
    xlab(NULL) +
    ylab(NULL) +
    theme(legend.position="none") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c(
                                 `San Antonio` = "#fbb4ae", Austin = "#b3cde3",
                                 Dallas = "#ccebc5", Houston = "#decbe4",
                                 Other = "#fed9a6"
                               )
                     )
```

All the lines were working a week ago, but when I reopened it today it won't knit due to that error. Not sure what to do.. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `geom_arc_bar()` function comes from the [ggforce package](https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/reference/geom_arc_bar.html); once the required libraries are loaded (ggplot2 for plotting, dplyr for `%>%`, and ggforce for `geom_arc_bar()`), the example appears to work as expected:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggforce)

pie_data <- read.table(text = "  city        sales end_angle start_angle mid_angle hjust vjust
'San Antonio'  1485     0.500       0         0.250     0     0
Austin       1656     1.06        0.500     0.778     0     0
Dallas       3066     2.09        1.06      1.57      0     1
Houston      4494     3.60        2.09      2.84      0     1
Other        7971     6.28        3.60      4.94      1     0", header = TRUE)

pie_data %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(
    x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = 0.4, r = 1,
    start = start_angle, end = end_angle,
    fill = city
  ) +
  geom_arc_bar() +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      x = 1.05 * sin(mid_angle),
      y = 1.05 * cos(mid_angle),
      label = city,
      hjust = hjust, vjust = vjust
    )
  ) +
  coord_fixed(
    xlim = c(-1.5, 1.65),
    ylim = c(-1.25, 1.25)
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "Houses Sold in Texas in 2015"
  ) +
  xlab(NULL) +
  ylab(NULL) +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(
    `San Antonio` = "#fbb4ae", Austin = "#b3cde3",
    Dallas = "#ccebc5", Houston = "#decbe4",
    Other = "#fed9a6"
  )
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-19 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Yes now it's working, thank you! I've realized that I loaded the library directly on the console last week and not inside my script. I feel dumb lol

Comment: Glad you solved your problem :)